# Fragment to activity intent not working

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

So, I'm doing a project, and i have a fragment called homepg_fragment.java and I'm trying to link an imageButton to go to another activity called MensAllShoes. But it keeps crashing. Can someone help me? I'm sort of new to android programming as you can see.

This is my homepg_fragment.java

```
package com.OP.slidingmenu.slidelist;

import com.nyp.integrateshoebox.MensAllShoes;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class HOMEPG_Fragment extends Fragment {

ImageButton ladies, gentlemen;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepg_fragment);


    ladies = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ladies1);
    gentlemen = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.men1);

}

public void cookie(View view) {
    Intent cookie = new Intent(getActivity(), MensAllShoes.class);
    startActivity(cookie);
}

private void setContentView(int viewallFragment) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepg_fragment, container,
            false);
    return rootView;

}

private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private ImageView findViewById(int ladies1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

And this is the XML.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/wctext" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ladies1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ladieshome" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/men1"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="212dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ladies1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menhome"
    android:onClick="cookie" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why have you defined your own methods for `setContentView`, `findViewById` and `getApplicationContext`? Get rid of them - it's definitely something you shouldn't be doing.

Remove the following line from `onCreate`...

```
setContentView(R.layout.homepg_fragment);
```

...and move the following lines into `onCreateView` after the line where you inflate your rootView...

```
ladies = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ladies1);
gentlemen = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.men1);
```

Also, as an aside, a `Fragment` should be self-contained and re-usable and shouldn't directly start an `Activity`. Instead you should create a 'callbacks' interface implemented by the `Activity` hosting the `Fragment`. You then call an interface method to tell the `Activity` which `Button` was pressed and let the `Activity` start the other `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your nethod

```
public void cookie(View view) {
     Intent cookie = new Intent(getActivity(), MensAllShoes.class);
     startActivity(cookie);
}
```

to

```
public void cookie(View view) {
     Intent cookie = new Intent(getActivity(), MensAllShoes.class);
     getActivity().startActivity(cookie);
}
```

Comment: It still crashes! LogCat says FATAL EXCEPTION: main and
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method cookie(View) in the activity class com.nyp.integrateshoebox.MenuActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ImageButton with id 'menu1'